# renaming array from value

Tags: php, arrays

i have a string, say its

```
ID=14,123@@ID=15,789@@
```

i exploded it with

```
$pieces = explode("@@", $contents);
```

so now i have a set of array

```
array(3) 
{ 
[0]=> string(69) "ID=14,123" 
[1]=> string(9) "ID=15,789" 
[2]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

then i would like to explode again the string within the array and used this

```
foreach ($pieces as $key => $value){
     $pieces[$key] = strpos( $value, "," ) ?
                explode( ",", $value ) :
                $value; 

     }
```

now i have an even more nested one

```
array(3) 
{ 
[0]=> array(2) 
   { 
   [0]=> string(5) "ID=14" 
   [1]=> string(3) "123" 
   } 
[1]=> array(2) 
   { 
   [0]=> string(5) "ID=15" 
   [1]=> string(3) "789" 
   } 
[2]=> string(0) 
   "" 
}
```

but what i wanted was so that the word "ID" can be replaced into the key of the array so it becomes

```
array 
{ 
[ID=14]=> "123" 
[ID=15]=> "789" 
}
```

how can that be done? i'm very unfamiliar with array but would love to learn.

Comment: All the keys in an array must be unique. That's how arrays work.

Comment: In `array { [ID]=> "123" [ID]=> "789" }`; how will you call the value `789` and how can you distinguish it from `123`?

Comment: thanks for clarification, what if i were to use ID=14, edited on original post. please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$contents = 'ID,123@@ID,789@@';
$pieces = explode("@@", $contents);

$parsed = array();
foreach ($pieces as $key => $value){
   $parsed[] = explode(',', $value);
}

$master = array();
foreach ($parsed as $ar) {
        $master[][$ar[0]] = $ar[1];
}
print_r($master);
```

Comment: thanks, indeed it is what i am looking for :) tho i really wish to learn, i can't seem to understand the phrase on foreach and within it. what does $pieces as $key => $value means actually? and $parsed[] would basically mean nothing right?

Comment: Yes. The `$key=>$value` isn't really necessary, but keeps me sane when doing foreach loops. `$parsed` is just a temporary array that holds the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have same indexes. In case that you meant indexes inside arrays, this will do the stuff:

```
$string = 'ID,123@@ID,789@@';

$result = array_map(function($item)
{
   $temp = explode(',', $item);
   return count($temp)==2?[$temp[0] => $temp[1]]:$temp;
},explode('@@', $string));

//var_dump($result);
```

Comment: sorry array_map is not what i am looking for, as pointed out by the others, i've edited my question, could you please have a look, tq.